# Using static records in dynamic zone with Samba and BIND_DLZ

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone, samba4, dynamic-dns

I've deployed Samba4 as AD controller using BIND_DLZ as a backend. It works ok. Now I have a bunch of servers with static IP's, and I would like to resolve them, but I can't find a way to do this.

So I googled for a few days, and didn't find anything really helpful. Then I decided to set up one more DNS server serving the same zone, but containing only static records - but I couldn't find a way to make this work. My idea was make this second server a forwarder in the first - but this doesn't work.

Questions are:

1) Is there any way to have static records in the dynamic zone (without fiddling around with static DHCP configuration)?

2) If no, than is it possible to make a two-server setup, where one will have dynamic records, and the other - static records? Where can I read about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, samba-tool can be used to achieve static records in dynamic zone.

```
samba-tool dns add <dnsserver> <domain> <hostname> <record type> <ipaddr> -Uadministrator
```

i.e.:

```
samba-tool dns add ns1 example.com host1 A 192.168.1.160 -Uadministrator
```

More about samba-tool: https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/samba-tool.8.html